# change total.txt file via php load

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess

I have this php script:

```
$total = file_get_contents('total.txt') + 1;
```

The script is supposed to add 1 to total.txt every time a user loads the code.

This code is faulty though. At random points, it decides to start raising the total.txt file by random amounts. At some other times, it decides to reset total.txt to 0.

I would rather this be in PHP, but HTML, htaccess, javascript, or anything else is okay too.

Why would this be? Is there any fix?

Comment: do you save data back to file?

Comment: I dont think so.

Comment: I don't see how .htaccess is relevant here

Comment: .htaccess might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused because the txt file is listed as total.txt not /total.txt

Alternately, It could be caused if you resource any file (including css) thats stored on your website.